# Left-join EXCLUDING matching records?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join, sql-server-2017

Traditional left-join returns all records from the left table, including matching records:

[image]

I want to use the join to ***exclude*** matching records, and return only non-matching records from the left table:

[image]

Shown below, is the code I came up with so far.
It uses a `WHERE` clause to weed out matching records - but this feels wrong somehow.
Is this the best way to do this? Or is there a better method of exclusive joining?

```
SELECT L.col1 ,
       L.col2 ,
FROM leftTable L
LEFT JOIN rightTable R ON R.col1 = L.col1
WHERE R.id IS NULL ;
```

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS "left-join returns all records from the left table" That's poor, but typical, phrasing--because left join returns rows with the columns of both inputs. You are trying to say something involving left input rows being subrows of returned rows.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `LEFT JOIN` method is fine.  It is optimized in many databases.  Personally, I prefer `NOT EXISTS`, because I think it is more concise:

```
SELECT L.col1, L.col2
FROM leftTable L
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM rightTable R WHERE R.col1 = L.col1);
```

That is, the logic is in one place (the `NOT EXISTS` expression) rather than being spread over two query clauses.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Except` to interpret

```
   Select * from table t LEFT JOIN 
     TABLE1 t1
   On t.id=t1.id
   Except
 SELECT * FROM TABLE1
```

Comment: `MINUS` isn't a keyword in SQL Server. Perhaps you're thinking of `EXCEPT`.

Comment: Its an operator for reference https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/minus.php

Comment: *"`MINUS` isn't a keyword in **SQL SERVER**"*: [db<>FIddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7832807463e1f9256fcd6cddcd478f25): `Msg 102 Level 15 State 1 Line 3
Incorrect syntax near 'MINUS'.` That is not to say it's isn't an operator in other SQL dialects, however, it is not an operator in T-SQL.

Comment: Infact, that link you reference even confirms this: *"**TIP:** The MINUS operator is not supported in all SQL databases. It can used in databases such as Oracle.

For databases such as SQL Server, PostgreSQL, and SQLite, use the [EXCEPT operator](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/except.php) to perform this type of query."* The OP has tagged SQL Server here, not Oracle.

Comment: ohhh.. I thought its oracle. Thanks.

Comment: No, the OP hasn't tagged Oracle at all here.

Comment: My bad `except` would work then but the logic was same. Will change it to Except

Comment: `EXCEPT` does not do exactly the same thing, because it removes duplicates.  That might be desirable, but it isn't equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong in using left join approach in fact it is standard approach and most people follow this way to exclude records and incremental inserts in some cases